# How do I deploy a program to a remote test validator?

Tags: solana-program, validator, testnet

I'm having some trouble deploying the [hello world program](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld) to a remote `solana-test-validator` hosted in Google Compute Engine.

---

On my local machine, when I run

```
solana program deploy dist/program/helloworld.so
```

I get stuck between the "Waiting for next block, 47 pending..." and the "Sending 39/47 transactions" messages and this never completes.

When I run the same command on the server itself, it succeeds in deploying the program, as expected.

---

Locally, I've modified my ~/.config/solana/cli/config.yml to point `json_rpc_url: "http://IP:PORT"` to the remote server. On the server, I've manually set the `--rpc-port` and `--dynamic-port-range` and opened the corresponding ports in both my `ufw` config and the GCE networking settings for both TCP and UDP traffic. Neither of these seem to have fixed the issue.

I'm able to do other things with the remote server, like query my balance, transfer SOL, and claim the airdrop, so I'm not sure why deploying a program doesn't work. Is there something else missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one's actually trickier than it seems.

Program deployment transactions are sent to the TPU port, and not the RPC port, so there's two things you need to do.

- Open up the TPU port, which may be the UDP or QUIC ports depending on your version.  It shows up when you start the validator:

```
$ solana-test-validator -r
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠠ Initializing...
Identity: 8BeVvgJ2FEr7WEp3agHbfTFNMCoKr1mwmyTncPMD8fxC
Genesis Hash: 6hW4qTMKu9soCj1wNKFWmysX6bpFEHPJSFnHF3q6N6hv
Version: 1.11.7
Shred Version: 4881
Gossip Address: 127.0.0.1:1024
TPU Address: 127.0.0.1:1027
JSON RPC URL: http://127.0.0.1:8899
```

- Specify the `--gossip-host` flag to your IP / hostname, so that the test validator specifies where to reach it. This information is used by the TPU client used for program deployments:

```
$ solana-test-validator --gossip-host my.ip.address.here
```

Comment: Specifying the `--gossip-host` did the trick! I'm guessing the TPU port was only bound to 127.0.0.1 and not 0.0.0.0 then.